# Editing Dialogs from old Win32 desktop app project in modern MFC project

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have a very old (pre-1998) Win32 desktop application created with Microsoft Visual C++ 5.0 (around 1997).
The application code has been updated so that the project compiles and runs.
The application also, as typical for a Windows application, includes some dialogs.

BUT the design layout of each of these dialogs (and all the controls within them) are 'coded' in dedicated .DLG code files - that are listed among all the header files in the Solution Explorer and NOT in the .RC file, as is seen in modern Visual Studio projects.

So, when the project is opened in Visual Studio 2022 these dialogs do not appear in the usual Dialog 'filter' in the Resource View and there is no ability to visually display, and interactively edit/modify, these dialogs with the dialog editor facility.
How can I get these dialogs to be displayed in the dialog editor?
Can I just copy and paste the 'code' somewhere into the project .RC file? And then delete the .DLG file?

An partial sample of the 'coding' of one of these .DLG files is shown below:

```
// PREF.DLG  resource dialog file

#ifndef __PREF_DFS_H
#include "PREF_DFS.H"
#endif

WindowPreferences DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 221, 190
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Windows"
FONT 8, "Helv"
BEGIN
GROUPBOX        "Layout",-1,6,2,208,58
CONTROL         "3D Grey",ID_FRAME_3D_GRAY,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | 
                WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,51,15,46,10
CONTROL         "3D Pattern",ID_FRAME_3D_PAT1,"Button",
                BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,159,15,46,10
CONTROL         "No Frame",ID_FRAME_PLAIN,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,51,
                41,46,10
CONTROL         "3D Decor",ID_FRAME_3D_DEC,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
                159,41,46,10
ICON            IDR_ICON2,1010,20,10,21,20
ICON            IDR_ICON3,1011,20,36,21,20
ICON            IDR_ICON4,1012,129,10,21,20
ICON            IDR_ICON5,1013,129,36,21,20
GROUPBOX        "Indicated time",-1,6,61,208,24
CONTROL         "Current",ID_TIME_CURRENT,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | 
                WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,21,70,60,10
```

Comment: yes, you can copy-paste this code to *.rc* file. need define `ID_FRAME_3D_GRAY` and other constants in *resource.h*, also must be `END` after last control of dialog

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply :-)    Presumably I would need to remove the short #ifndef block of code before copying it to the .RC file?

Comment: Also, when copying the dialog 'code' to the .RC file does the placement within the .RC file matter? Or, can I just paste it into the file at the very end of the existing .RC file content?

Comment: File extension have no meaning, and never had a meaning. The text you've posted is a standard resource definition file. You can simply rename it to *whatever.rc*, and the build system will have the resource compiler translate it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave those files unchanged, and set up a custom build step that runs the resource compiler on them.

Comment: Can you make use of the resource includes option in the IDE to include those files? Personally I would copy / paste them into the RC file in the right place though.